# How to get a value of a D3D12_RESOURCE_STATES from a resource?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, directx-12

**H**ello!

Is it possible to read a current **D3D12_RESOURCE_STATES** state for a **resource**?

Thank you

Comment: State is write only in d3d12, you set it on resource creation, then change it using transitions. But you can't ask for the current state at any given time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a comment to the question is an answer by @mrvux